# I can not check that parent was removed

Tags: jquery, parent

I have simple code:

```
    $(this).parent().remove();
    if ($(this).parent())
    {
        alert( "exist" ); // alert always "exist"
    }
```

Why **li** element ( $(this).parent() ) was removed but alert in this scope - that not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if a jQuery object is truthy. All Javascript objects are truthy, so the if statement will always be entered. Instead you can check if the number of matched elements is truthy:

```
$(this).parent().remove();
if($(this).parent().length)
    alert( "exist" ); // alert "exist" if this still has a parent element.
```

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery constructor always returns something. Try `$(this).parent().length` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You removed your previous parent, but now you have a new one, which will be returned by the second call to `$(this).parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
parent.remove();
if (parent.length) {
    alert('exists');
}
```

Comment: But parent.length after parent removing always return 1  - its ok ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe `if ($(this).parent().length > 0) {` because jQuery allways return jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

Using

`$(this).parent().remove()`

will remove your current object handle $(this) too (in this case child of the parent).  So if you're checking `$(this).parent()` , it actually doesn't exist.

To check, you have to use another handle

```
$parent=$(this).parent();
$(this).parent().remove();
if ($parent.size())
{
    alert( "exist" ); // alert always "exist"
}
```

Comment: Removing an object doesn't destroy it.  It just removes it from the DOM - it still exists as long as there is a JS reference to it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But isn't $(this) as a reference to the DOM element is removed when removing it's parent ? We use $(this).parent().remove() in dynamically added rows in forms frequently.

Comment: Just because `.remove()` was called doesn't change the value in `this`.  It's still a reference to the same node it was before the call to `.remove()` and thus it's node is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the truthy issue for jQuery objects already mentioned, the main issue is that `.remove()` removes the parent from the DOM, but it doesn't destroy it until there are no references left to it.  Since you have a reference to `this`, the removed objects still exist.   In fact, a whole object hierarchy can be removed from the DOM and still exist.  That's the same state that DOM objects are in when you create them, but haven't yet inserted them into the DOM.

If you look at the source for jQuery `.remove()`, it calls `removeChild()` and destroys all jQuery state associated with the object, but does not destroy the DOM objects themselves.  They will get cleaned up eventually by the garbage collector if there are no JS references to them.

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` does not actually remove anything - it disconnects it from the HTML, and leaves it as an orphan, and lets the javascript garbage collector find it and discard it.

BUT, since you have the variable `this` the garbage collector will not discard it since it's in use.

And because of that your code finds it.